# Having trouble with ascending insertion sort with strings in C

Tags: c, string, strcpy, insertion-sort

I am having trouble sorting out a list of names in c. I have code for sorting the names, but when I go to print them out they still are in the same order as they were at the beginning so something isnt right. So the function that I need help with is the sort_data function. I will post all of my code so it can help you guys out with helping me! Thanks a lot in advance, this function has been killing me all morning.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LEN 25

void insert_data(char **strings, const char* filename, int size);
void allocate(char ***strings, int size);
void sort_data(char **strings, int size);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    if(argc != 4){
            printf("Wrong number of args");
    }

    char **pointer;
    int size = atoi(argv[1]);


    allocate(&pointer, size);
    insert_data(pointer, argv[2], size);
    sort_data(pointer,size);
}

void sort_data(char **strings, int size){

    int i, j;
    char temp[MAX_STRING_LEN];

    for( i = 1; i < size; i++){
            strcpy(temp, strings[i]);
            j = i - 1;
            while( j >= 0 && strcmp(strings[i], temp) > 0)
            {
                    strcpy(strings[j+1], strings[j]);
                    j = j - 1;
            }
            strcpy(strings[j+1], temp);

    }

    int z;
    for(z = 0; z < size; z++){
    printf("\n%s", strings[z]);
    }
}

void allocate(char ***strings, int size){

    int i;
    *strings =  malloc(sizeof(**strings) * size);

    for( i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    (*strings)[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_STRING_LEN);
    }
}

void insert_data(char **strings, const char* filename, int size){

    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(filename, "r");

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){

    fscanf(input,"%24s", strings[i]);

    }

    fclose(input);
}
```

The list that I am reading in is as follows:

- matt
- susan
- mark
- david
- aden
- phil
- erik
- john
- caden
- mycah

So I need to get this list in alphabetical order, but when I run my code and print out this list after I run the sort function, they are still in this order. Thanks alot once again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

What are you passing in for 'size' here?

In sort_data(), you seem to use it as the maximum string size:

```
char temp[size];
```

And also as the number of strings in the list:

```
for( i = 1; i < size; i++)
```

I don't know if this is your only problem, but it's bound to bite you at some point.

ETA: Your while loop needs work.  Notice that in each iteration you are comparing 'strings[i]' to 'temp', having set them equal to each other before the loop.  Nothing inside that inner loop will be executed, and at the end of it you will just copy 'temp' back to the same location in 'strings'.

Take a few minutes to map out exactly what needs to happen each time you run the loop.  Run through it on paper, and write down the contents of your array and the values of 'i' and 'j'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this would of definetly hurt me in the future, but there still is something that isnt working because the names still arent in order

Comment: THANKS FOR THE HELP I FIGURED IT OUT